# iPad Air 2 charger getting warm

Tags: ipad, charging

My charger has been fine until recently although I noticed it getting warmer.  Last night it wouldn't charge at all and this morning it was so hot I could just about touch it with bare hands. I couldnt get the iPad to start up and eventually noticed a message "only use Apple charging devices as others may cause harm" it was then that I began to use my MacBook Pro USB.

The iPad charges okay from my MacBook Pro USB, is this a common occurrence? I bought the iPad as a manufacturers refurbished and has been fine in every other way.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there may be a defect with either the charger or the iPad. I suggest taking it to an authorized Apple store so that they can run diagnostics on it, and potentially repair it.

Answer (score 1):

When something is painful to touch - I would always seek Apple service - remotely or in person if that is convenient.

- https://locate.apple.com

There are multiple safety mechanisms to prevent overheating and fire, but if there is one thing wrong - another thing could fail too and I would want to give Apple the change to fix things under warranty or exchange it if they feel it's a safety issue.

It's almost certainly the charger that's faulty - the iPad does draw a good amount of power so in a warm room, the charger can run hot and be fine, so it could be nothing at all too. Better safe and if you can borrow an infrared thermometer or use this as an excuse [to spend $15-30 and buy one](http://amzn.com/B00DMI632G) - it would be worthwhile to measure exactly what the case temperature is compared to ambient temperature. That would tell a lot more about whether it's within specifications or overheating.

---

Once you're sure the heat is normal, then you can look into the cable and maybe if there is lint covering a pin that's causing the "incompatible / non-apple detection" but that also seems to indicate a hardware issue somewhere along the chain.